# how to get the content of the page in an modal using colorbox jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I am having a page with print icon in there. Now, I need to grab that class and pull the content of that page in an modal using colorbox and than change the print class to a new name so that i can execute actual print by window.print. Is there a way I can pull the content from present page using $("selector").html() and place inside the modal. Moreover, I need to pull the css as well.

thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the html of an object to the html of another object:

```
$('#modal_dialog').html($('selector').html());
```